# App is not login in to the clicking of the first time login button

Tags: react-native

Problem : App is not login when clicking first time login button. when clicking the first time keyboard is hiding. Second time only able to click the login button.

Expecting: App should login/land on the homepage when click the login button in first click

Comment: Hello,
You need to add your code to check where is the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.